# Zero dimensional local ring with maximal ideal not principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Probably it is well known. I am looking for a zero dimensional local ring with maximal ideal not principal.

Comment: Just take $K[X,Y]$ ($K$ a field) and localize at $(X,Y)$

Comment: Ops, I forgot that it must be 0-dimensional.

Comment: Well, then $K[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)$ (it's already local)

Comment: @AndreaMori Please consider putting it as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the quotient ring
$$
R=\frac{K[X,Y]}{(X,Y)^2}
$$
where $K$ is a field. It is zero-dimensional because there's a bijection between ideals of $R$ and ideals of $K[X,Y]$ containing $(X,Y)^2$ under which prime ideals correspond to prime ideals, and $(X,Y)$ is the only prime ideal containing $(X,Y)^2$.

As a by-product of this argument, we also see that $R$ is local because it has just one prime ideal, thus maximal, namely ${\frak m}=(\bar X,\bar Y)$.

Finally, if ${\frak m}$ were principal, since $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ cannot be a common multiple of some non-invertible element of lower degree (there are none!) we would have
$$
X-Y\in(X,Y)^2
$$
But this is impossible, because $(X,Y)^2$ contains no polynomial of degree 1.

Answer (score 3):

Another nice example is $\mathcal O_{\mathbf C_p}/p\mathcal O_{\mathbf C_p}$, where $\mathcal O_{\mathbf C_p}$ is the ring of integers of the completion $\mathbf C_p$ of $\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$. It has dimension $0$, but its maximal ideal is not even finitely generated.

Comment: You can do the same as Andrea but with infinitely many variables to get a rather simpler example of the same phenomenon.

Comment: @Mariano: That's true. I'm mentioning this example only because $\mathcal O_{\mathbf C_p}$ is a ring which occurs naturally in number theory.